# How does StackOverflow know when there are new answers to a question?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forums

If this question has already been asked I appologies, please point me in the right direction.

I was wondering if anyone has any insight into how StackOverflow pops up the "n new answers have been posted, load new answers" thing at the top of a question when you are adding a post. This seems like a very useful function for my forum web-site and I would like to know how it is done. I assume some ajax or advanced javascript of some kind.

Comment: Edited to make this more clearly a real question.

Comment: That is a much better question then mine, thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at this SO blog post: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/solving-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem/

> That said, the one implementable
> recommendation that came out of this
> discussion is an active, GMail like
> notification when you are composing an
> answer. We agreed with this feature
> request, so Jarrod implemented it.
> Here’s how it works:
>
> 1. When you start composing a reply, a timer is created.
> 2. Every minute, the page checks itself to see if new answers have
>    arrived.
> 3. If new answers arrive, the notification bar will tell you how
>    many, and offer to update the page for
>    you.
> 4. Answer updates are performed AJAX style, so they don’t interrupt
>    your current answer.

Answer (score 3):

At a guess it's using a jQuery timer object to query a JSON webservice every *n* seconds. Check out http://docs.jquery.com and [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200925065333/http://geekswithblogs.net/JuanDoNeblo/archive/2007/10/24/json_in_aspnetajax_part2.aspx).

How ironic... an answer has been posted as I was writing this.